# Problems at running ImageDataBunch in Deepnote

Tags: numpy, deepnote

I'm having trouble running this line of code in Deepnote, does anyone know why?

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train="train", valid ="test",ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=(256,256), bs=32, num_workers=4).normalize()
```

The error says:

```
NameError: name 'ImageDataBunch' is not defined
```

And previously, I have imported the Fastai library. So I don't get it!

Answer (score 2):

The FastAI setup in Deepnote is not that straightforward. It's best to use a [custom environment](https://docs.deepnote.com/environment/custom-environments) where you set stuff up in a `Dockerfile` and everything works afterwards in the notebook. I am not sure if the `ImageDataBunch` or whatever you're trying to do works the same way in FastAI v1 and v2, but here are the details for v1.

This is a Dockerfile which sets up the FastAI environment via conda:

```sh
# This is Dockerfile

FROM deepnote/python:3.9


RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
RUN bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
ENV PATH $HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH
ENV PYTONPATH $HOME/miniconda

RUN $HOME/miniconda/bin/conda install python=3.9 ipykernel -y
RUN $HOME/miniconda/bin/conda install -c fastai -c pytorch fastai -y
RUN $HOME/miniconda/bin/python -m ipykernel install --user --name=conda
ENV DEFAULT_KERNEL_NAME "conda"
```

After that, you can test the `fastai` imports in the notebook:

```py
import fastai
from fastai.vision import *

print(fastai.__version__)

ImageDataBunch
```

And if you download and unpack [this sample MNIST dataset](https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-ai-sample/mnist_tiny.tgz), you should be able to load the data like you suggested:

```py
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train="train", valid ="test",ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=(256,256), bs=32, num_workers=4).normalize()
```

Feel free to check out or clone [my Deepnote project](https://deepnote.com/project/FastAI-v1-in-Deepnote-V2xO7DOZSGegaVmqPXofUA) to continue working on this.